# Как растянуть поле input на всю ширину ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица, в верхней строке которой вставлены поля для фильтрации. Как сделать, чтобы эти поля input были растянуты на всю ширину ячеек.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark" id="table-show">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <div >
            <tr class='table-filters'>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="input-filter"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>...</tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

вот так:

```html
.input-filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

не работает.

Вот что у меня показывает в браузере (я добавил еще одну строчку для наглядности):
[Таблица](http://prnt.sc/w94isl)

Comment: Они у Вас сейчас и так во всю ширину ячеек. Или что Вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так...Ячейки `<td>` ограничивают ширину

```
<td style="width: 100%">
   <input type="text" class="input-filter"/>
</td>
```